# Is this a divide and conquer algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

I'm doing a program for class what given a string obtain the longest substring made of a consecutive {consonant, vowel} pattern, but I was asked to do it in Divide And Conquer fashion. This is my algoritm but I dont know if it's a D&V one. And if it isn't, how do I modify it to be as such?

```
int cadenaMasLargaDeVC(string str) {
    int n = str.size();                    
    string strRes, strTmp = "";  
    int posRes = 0;
    set<char> st;
    st.insert('a');
    st.insert('e');
    st.insert('i');
    st.insert('o');
    st.insert('u');
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout << i << " ";
        if(st.find(str[i]) == st.end() && st.find(str[i+1]) != st.end()){
            strTmp += string(str[i]) + str[i+1];
            i++;
        } else{
            strTmp = "";
        }          
        if(strTmp.size() > strRes.size()){
            strRes = strTmp;
            posRes = i - strRes.size() + 2;
        }
        if(strRes.size() > (n-i)) break;
    }
    cout << strRes << endl;
    return posRes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Divide & Conquer paradigm generally have the below precise steps:

1. Dividing the larger problem to smaller sub-problems.
2. Conquer have Conquer and Combine Steps where you try to solve the basic (atomic) problem which you couldn't divide further and keep combining them.

In the code you gave, There is no division step involved. You are only making pass though two consecutive characters in string and keep tracking the longest you get till the i-th position. It's similar to passing through a given array and keeping max variable and updating it as and when required.

Perhaps the question was meant to divide and go through all two length sub-string (the atomic problem), check if consecutive characters are in the way asked and appropriately incrementing the 'count' while combining.